# Selenium Fetches Different Source on AWS Lambda

Tags: web-scraping, aws-lambda, selenium-chromedriver

I have the following code locally:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
driver= webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=chrome_options, )
driver.get(url)
print(driver.page_source)
```

In AWS, I have something similar:

```
options = Options()
options.binary_location = '/opt/headless-chromium'
options.add_argument("--headless")
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--single-process')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')    
driver= webdriver.Chrome('/opt/chromedriver',chrome_options=options)
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(5)
print(driver.page_source)
```

The code compiles on AWS and there are no errors. However, I am getting different output when I print the page source. I am running it from the same region. Not sure if this helps, but the HTML I am trying to load is from a dynamic website. However, it works fine locally, and I even added a delay to the lambda code. What is the reason this does not work? Thanks everyone - I have been struggling to figure this out for a while!

EDIT
[Here](https://www.jpg.store/collection/claypez) is the URL I am trying to scrape. The AWS code only prints out a few HTML tags but the local code prints out all of the NFTs that are listed (lambda code doesn't show any of them).

Comment: What's the difference it prints out? Is the Lambda in a VPC? Are you following any documentation - its doable https://dev.to/awscommunity-asean/creating-an-api-that-runs-selenium-via-aws-lambda-3ck3

Comment: @JeremyThompson Thank you for commenting Jeremy! I actually followed that tutorial pretty closely to get everything to compile. The difference is, the lambda code only prints out a little bit of HTML - a couple div tags and header tags, but that's it. The local code prints out hundreds of lines of HTML. Will update my description with actual URL